# Not working add number to existing contacts in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, addressbook, abaddressbook

I want to add a phone number into existing contact. This code working perfectly in iOS8 but not into iOS11. Not getting any errors but while ABNewPersonViewController opens I cannot see new Phone Number.

```
-(void)addToExstingContact{

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *personPicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    personPicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:personPicker animated:true completion:nil];
}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

    [peoplePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{

        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(phoneNumbers);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(newPhoneNumber), kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);

        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);

        ABNewPersonViewController *view = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
        view.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
        view.displayedPerson = person;

        UINavigationController *newNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];
        [self presentViewController:newNavigationController animated:true completion:nil];
    }];
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker{
    [peoplePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the docs:

> The Address Book UI framework is deprecated in iOS 9. Use the APIs
>   defined in the ContactsUI framework instead. To learn more, see
>   [ContactsUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui?language=objc).

Maybe you should rewrite this code to the contacts framework to make it work on 11?

One example of this is here:
https://www.appsfoundation.com/post/create-edit-contacts-with-ios-9-contacts-ui-framework

Comment: Then it should not be open ABNewPersonViewController also.

Comment: Yes, everything AB** needs to be changed to CN** analogs.